# ID/Key definitions in EMF (Meta) Models

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I'm stuck with a very basic problem regarding EMF, here's what i've got.

```
EClass A:
  aID : EInteger (Key: true)

EClass B:
  bID : EInteger (Key: true)

EClass C: 
  Reference refA: to elements of A, containment: true, EKeys: aID, 0 .. n 
  Reference refB: to elements of B, containment: true, EKeys: bID, 0 .. n
```

Now here's the problem. In both my a and b list I'd like to have IDs from 0 to n. However, when I do this, I get the message:

```
The ID '1' of 'A' collides with that of 'B'
```

I hope my problem is described clearly. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An EAttribute which is set as "ID" should be unique resource-wide. If you want to reference elements using a myReference[name="SomeName"] construction then you should use eKeys, then the eKeyed attribute should have a unique value within a reference.

I am under the impression you defined "aID" and "bID" as "ID's whereas that's not what you really want here.

Answer (score 0):

That could be resolved using the OO hierarchy. You just need to extend A and B from a common Abstract class that contains the id attribute, and it is set as ID in emf properties.